# Comparing two dataframe and replacing the column values

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two dataframe [image: df]

[image: df1]

I need to compare both dataframe and my output should in such a way that if the values a df1 is present in df leave it as it is else it should be replaced by Out. For example values of column in Level_count should be like L1,L1,L1,L2,L2,L2,L2,Out,Out,Out (as L3 and l4 are not in df1) like this same way i need to compare Edu and Occ as well.

This is my desired output
[image: Output]
Could anyone help me in solving out this solution.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please provide some input data as text, show us your desired output and your latest attempts. See **[mcve]**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need:

```
df2_dict=df2.to_dict(orient='list')
# {'Level_Count': ['L1', 'L2'], 'Edu': ['MBBS', None], 'Occ': ['MBBS1', None]}

for c in df1.columns:
    df1[c]=df1[c].apply(lambda x: x if x in df2_dict[c] else 'out')
```

Output:

```
    Level_Count Edu Occ
0   L1  MBBS    MBBS1
1   L1  MBBS    MBBS1
2   L1  out     out
3   L2  MBBS    MBBS1
4   L2  MBBS    MBBS1
5   L2  MBBS    MBBS1
6   L2  MBBS    MBBS1
7   out MBBS    MBBS1
8   out out     out
9   out MBBS    MBBS1
```